# How to insert exact string regardsless

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to insert (-i) an exact line of code into a file using sed. This is the line to be inserted:

> "Sometext" . $index++ . "\t" . 'dummytext' . "\t"'\

This is what I tried (shell script):

```
sed -i '66 i\"Sometext" . $index++ . "\t" . 'dummytext' . "\t"' filename
```

This is the result in filename:

> "Sometext" . $index++ . " " . dummytext . "   "

where it should be:

> "Sometext" . $index++ . "\t" . 'dummytext' . "\t"

Obviously some character are being interpreted by sed as a sed commands, and I want to avoid that.

Any pointers/hints/tips with the above example in mind please?

Comment: Is the problem the `\t`? Older versions of sed do not support `\t`, you have to enter a "hard" tab yourself, try Ctrl-V Tab.

Answer (score 1):

Some extra escapes and quotes:

```
sed -i '2 i\"Sometext" . $index++ . "\\t" . '\''dummytext'\'' . "\\t"' filename
```